# Change length of dashed line to match input string length?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string name;
int income;
int tax;

cout << "What is your full name?  ";
getline(cin,name);
cout << "What is your annual income?  ";
cin >> income;

if (income < 50000)
{
    tax = income*0.33;
}
else { tax = income*0.38; }

cout << "\t\t\t" << name << ": Tax Report" << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t" << "-------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Income =$" << income << endl;
cout << "Tax =$" << tax << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I would like the line of hyphens to match the length of the name string regardless of its length. I am in an introductory c++ class and I am sure there is a simple way to do this. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << "\t\t\t" << string(name.length() + 12, '-') << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

just put in this line, instead of your current dash line

```
cout << "\t\t\t" << std::string(name.length(), '-') << endl;
```

for further information see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    std::string name( "01234567890" );

    std::cout << "\t\t\t" << name << ": Tax Report" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t" << std::setfill( '-' ) << std::setw( name.size() ) 
              << '-' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
    01234567890: Tax Report
    -----------
```

If you want that all preceding line would be underlined then you need tp add the size of string ": Tax Report" to the argument of `std:;setw` For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    std::string name( "01234567890" );

    std::cout << "\t\t\t" << name << ": Tax Report" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t" << std::setfill( '-' ) << std::setw( name.size() + 12 ) 
              << '-' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the porgram output is

```
01234567890: Tax Report
-----------------------
```

Thus all you need is to use functions `std::setfill` and  `std::setw` declared in header `<iomanip>`. There is no need to a create a temporary object of type `std::string` because it is inefficient..

Answer (score 0):

You can make a string of hyphens of a certain length. Get the length by first building a string for the name line and then calling its length method. Here is an example:

```
std::string hyphens;
hyphens.assign(length, '-');
```

check out thislink for more details on using strings:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/